# What value should I give the scope attribute in my manifest.json file when serving a Progressive Web App from a local IP address with a port number?

Tags: scope, progressive-web-apps, localserver, manifest.json, web-app-manifest

I am having a problem with web app manifest scope on my local Node JS test server. I cannot get the correct scope because the port number on the IP address gets in the way. I am accessing my server with the following address:

```
https://192.168.0.101:2468/
```

When I use Chrome dev tools to look at my manifest, under the Application tab it shows the url of the manifest file to be: `:2468/manifest.json` but `:2468` is not a directory in my root folder.

I keep all my files in the root directory, including the `server.js`, the `manifest.json`, and the index, called `my-app.html`

```
_ website-directory
|_ server.js
|_ manifest.json
|_ my-app.html
```

In my manifest file I have:

```
{

  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "my-app.html"

}
```

Everything works perfectly when I upload the code to my Github Pages site here: [working example.](https://frankpoth.info/content/pop-vlog/javascript/2017/017-offline-web-app/web-app.html) I think the problem is coming from the `:2468` behind my IP address. I do not have this problem with a fully qualified domain name like I have with Github Pages.

If I try to put the port number into the manifest's scope like so:

```
  "scope": "./:2468/",
  "start_url": "my-app.html"
```

It breaks the scope of my manifest and I get this warning: `Manifest: property 'scope' ignored. Start url should be within scope of scope URL.` Which makes perfect sense because `:2468` is not a folder in my directory. It's just something Chrome decided to attach to the url of my manifest file.

How do I resolve the scope of my manifest file to ignore the port number? Why does Chrome dev tools indicate that my manifest is in the `:2468` directory that does not exist?

The reason this is a problem is because my web app will not open in app mode, with a full screen window and splash screen. It only opens in a browser with a url bar and doesn't seem to be using the app manifest at all.

UPDATE: 11/05/17

By using the URL `https://192.168.0.101:2468/my-app.html` I can access my web app without dev tools showing `:2468/` in my manifest url. My app does install to both the home screen and the app drawer, but it only opens in a browser rather than a full screen app with a splash screen. I get no warnings about the manifest scope, and my service worker registers and runs perfectly. I am beginning to think that progressive web apps cannot be installed from an IP address, but only fully qualified domain names. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, Progressive Web Apps must be installed at a somewhat proper URL because they require that scope to operate properly. Without the scope being enforced, a rogue service worker could gain access to sites that it shouldn't.

Comment: Is it possible that the Android Intent Filter being generated from my IP address is not valid? This filter tells Android how to open my web page (in app mode or in a browser). As far as I can tell, I have no power to control what is in this intent filter, and Chrome generates it based on my page URL and my app manifest.

Comment: Have you specified the `display` property in your web app manifest? It sounds like you want it set to `display: standalone`

Comment: I have tried setting it to standalone and fullscreen. It is not a manifest problem, as everything works fine when I add to home screen from my Github site, it simply doesn't work when I add to home screen from my local ip address.